# How do I find out & treat what is eating my hibiscus leaves

Tags: diseases, leaves

I was wondering what might be eating away at my hibiscus and how do I protect my poor little plant.

I don't visually see any bugs on or under the leaves.

Update: This plant is in a pot. Location: North Texas.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what part of the world are you in (local pests vary round the world) and is this plant in a pot?

Comment: And do you have a cat or small dog? That looks like the damage my Chihuahua does to my potted plants when she gets to them.

Comment: @Bamboo - North TX and yes, plant is in a pot.

Comment: @michelle - No cats or dogs or other pets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look where insects live.  In this case:

- look on the underside of the leaves
- look in the soil at the base of the plant
- go out at night with a flashlight and see who has shown up for dinner

Keep in mind that some insects arrive and stay and others just pass through.  If you don't see any and there is no new damage then they might have been eaten!

Answer (score 3):

I reckon its vine weevil; the black variety seems to be endemic where you are. The damage is certainly typical of vine weevil and plants in pots are their favourites. Not sure what pesticides are available where you are to treat them with - in the UK, we tend to use nematodes which are watered onto the soil in the pot at certain times of year. Provado makes a drench for use in pots specifically against vine weevil, again to be used at the right time, but that contains neonicotinoids which destroy bee colonies.

If you want to find the vine weevils, taking a flashlight out at night and having a good look should reveal some, as Kevinsky suggests.